# Bootstrap datetime picker disable past time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Bootsrap 3 (eonasdan-datetimepicker) Datetime Picker. I am wondering how can i prevent user to select past time. I find the documentation doesn't say much about how to disable past time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the [minDate](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) option is what I would recommend `minDate: moment()`

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment()
});
```

[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/1o3b3b1o/3/)

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince, `momet()` is from the date library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. it disables past date and time.

```
 $(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      startDate: new Date()
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```